# View Transitions in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, mobile

I'm building a mobile app with Backbone.js and ratchet. Routers use the method for changing view. Now I want to add an animation when you switch from one view to another. I'm trying this code, you can give me a hand.

EDIT: 
I would like to add the classic animation that ottine to change the page on iPhone. I tried to do it this way:

View:

```
var SettingsView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName:  "section",
className: "pt",
initialize: function(){
},

render: function(){
  var template = _.template($('#settingsview-template').html(),{});
  this.$el.html(template);
  return this;
},


getAnimEndEventName: function(){
    var animEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
        'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
        'animation' : 'animationend'
    };
    return animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
},

open: function(){
var _this = this;
  this.$el.addClass("animated bounceInLeft");
},
close: function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.$el.addClass("animated bounceOutLeft").on(this.AnimEndEventName, function(){
    _this.removeClass("animated bounceInLeft, animated bounceOutLeft"); 
});
}
});
```

routes:

```
settingsViewPage: function(){              

   var view = new SettingsView(); 
   $(".container").html(view.render().el);
   this.currentView.close();
   view.open();
   this.currentView = view;            
},
```

I get the error from the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of animation you want to use but it could be called before render your views.

something like this in your router file.

routes: { 
        ""                :   "startPage",
        "PageHome"        :   "homePage",
        "PageShow"        :   "showViewPage"
    },

```
startPage: function(){
    //HERE START THE ANIMATION.
    var view = new StartView(); 
    $(".container").html(view.render().el);  
            // STOP THE ANIMATION            
},

homePage: function(){
    //HERE START THE ANIMATION.
    var view = new HomeView(); 
    $(".container").html(view.render().el);   
    // STOP THE ANIMATION           
},
```

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is done here but I do not understand where

```
close: function(){
        var _this = this;
        this.$el.addClass("animated bounceOutLeft").on(this.AnimEndEventName, function(){
        _this.removeClass("animated bounceInLeft, animated bounceOutLeft"); 
    });
```